# Why isn't my attempt at making an FPS shooter zoom working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**OBJECTIVE**

I am using [this script](https://forum.unity.com/threads/a-free-simple-smooth-mouselook.73117/) I got from Unity's forums to move my camera around. It works perfectly and this is exactly the style of camera I want. Here it is in action:

https://streamable.com/j7ozps

I wanted to create a zoom effect when the user holds the right mouse button.

**PROBLEM**

After zooming in, the aim is off by a lot. Here's what happens:
https://streamable.com/8aiil0

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            int layerMask = 1 << CombatManager.GROUND_LAYER; // -> public const int GROUND_LAYER = 8;
            Ray mouseClick = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);                         
            RaycastHit[] hitInfos;                                                                      
            float maxDistance = 100.0f;

            hitInfos = Physics.RaycastAll(mouseClick, maxDistance,
                                            layerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);                

            mainCamera.fieldOfView = 10;
            mainCamera.transform.LookAt(hitInfos[0].point);
        }
        else
            mainCamera.fieldOfView = startingFieldOfView;
```

I also tried swapping the order of the LookAt and field of view assignment.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that what you want is to zoom towards the cursor position, not towards where the ray hits which are likely not the same point. To check that out you can draw a debug cube where the ray hits, to check if the point you are looking at is the one you need, like so:

```
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
cube.transform.position = hitInfos[0].point;
```

Check [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) that gives you the worldspace point created by converting the screen space point at the provided distance z from the camera plane.

What I would try:

```
Vector3 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
//check if this is the point you want to look at
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
cube.transform.position = point;
//look at it
mainCamera.transform.LookAt(point);
```

It should not mind if you are using the `cam.nearClipPlane` or the `cam.farClipPlane` in the `ScreenToWorldPoint` function, but I would play with that in case something is not working as intended.

```
Vector3 screenPoint = Input.mousePosition;
screenPoint.z = Camera.main.farClipPlane;
Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying!! Turns out the point was indeed the one I wanted. Your create primitive trick allowed me to debug it. The problem was in my MouseLook script. Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately I thought I had figured out what was wrong but I was mistaken. The point was indeed correct and the problem is in the MouseLook script but I spent hours trying to make it work to no avail. If you are feeling bored I created a new question including a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71889482/zoom-cameras-aim-is-off-quaternions-completely-baffling-me

Comment: If the point is correct `transform.Lookat()` should do the job. Maybe when you zoom in the point is at the depth of your face and you need to take in backwards increa asing the z??

Comment: I would check that the point is tje correct one but not only regarding the screem 2d space but in the world. On the other hand if you play around with `transform.Lookat()` you'll see it does the job so you must be close

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! The problem is making it compatible with my MouseLook script. The point is indeed 100% correct and If I turn the other script off LookAt works and the zoom is perfect but as soon as it's turned back on again the screen is immediately shifted out of position. I managed to trace the problem to one specific line where the Y rotation is applied. Unfortunately I don't understand Quaternions very well so I have been unable to go any further